# Existence of a degree $ \geq m $ irreducible component of a hypersurface in $ \mathbb{P}^{n} $ of degree $ \geq m. $

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ m,n \geq 1 $ be positive integers, and suppose $ g $ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $ \geq m. $

I am wondering about the possible degrees of the irreducible components of the hypersurface $ F = \lbrace g = 0 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}. $ In particular, is there always an irreducible component of degree $ \geq m$?

I don't know how to begin investigating this question, or if the question is too general. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is trivially false if $ g $ is not itself irreducible; for instance, take $ g(X, Y, Z) = X^2 - Y^2 $ for $ m = n = 2 $. In this case, the vanishing set is the union of two projective lines and so there is no irreducible component of degree $ \geq 2 $.

If $ g $ is irreducible, then $ F $ is itself irreducible and of degree $ m $, so the claim is true.